# $90!$ when divided by $n$, gives an odd number. What can be the minimum and the maximum values of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

$90!$ when divided by $n$, gives an odd number. How could we find the minimum and the maximum values of $n$?

I am not sure how to approach this one, any ideas?

Comment: maximum value of $n$ is $90!$ because $90!/90!=1$ which is odd, right?

Comment: $\dfrac{90!}{2^{86}}$ is an odd number.

Comment: What is the 2-adic valuation of $90$? There's a nice formula for this, try some small examples.

Comment: @J.M. I think that's an answer.

Comment: You know that $n$ has to contain every factor of $2$ in $90$.  That's the minimum $n$ can be.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20737/prime-powers-that-divide-a-factorial

Comment: @Neal. That's incorrect. $2|90$ and $4\not|90$, but $4|90!$ so $\frac{90!}{2}$ is not even.

Comment: @J.M.: There is some problem with your equation.

Comment: @Paul: I reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A result of Legendre](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factorial.html) (formula 5 in the link, and sometimes also attributed to [de Polignac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula)) states that the largest power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is given by

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_p n\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

The highest power of $2$ that divides $90!$ is thus given by

$$\left\lfloor\frac{90}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{90}{4}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{90}{8}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{90}{16}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{90}{32}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{90}{64}\right\rfloor=86$$

and thus $\dfrac{90!}{2^{86}}$ is odd. As [Paul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16158) mentions, $\dfrac{90!}{90!}=1$ is also odd.

Comment: btw how we know for sure that $ \dfrac{90!}{2^{86}}$ is odd?

Comment: Because dividing by $2^{86}$ leaves only the odd factors?

Comment: $$\begin{split}\frac{90!}{2^{86}}=&3^{44}\times 5^{21}\times 7^{13}\times 11^8\times 13^6\times 17^5\times 19^4\times 23^3\times 29^3\times 31^2\times 37^2\times 41^2\times 43^2\times\\&47\times 53\times 59\times 61\times 67\times 71\times 73\times 79\times 83\times 89\end{split}$$

Comment: It's maybe worth mentioning that this result is really easy. The meaning of the formula is the following: out of the numbers 1,...,90, there will be $\lfloor 90/2 \rfloor$ even numbers, and for each of these a factor of 2 in $90!$. Moreover, there will be $\lfloor 90/4 \rfloor$ which are also divisible by four, and each of these contributes an additional factor of two to $90!$. There will be $\lfloor 90/8 \rfloor$ ones divisible by eight, and for each of these *yet another* factor of two. And so on.