# Prove or name this identity: the number of factors of $p$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ is $(s_p(k)+s_p(n-k)-s_p(n))/(p-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

you can count the number of factors of $p$ that are in $\binom{n}{k}$ for prime $p$. Let $s_p(n)$ be the sum of the digits of $n$ in base $p$.  Then, the number of factors of $p$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ is $(s_p(k)+s_p(n-k)-s_p(n))/(p-1)$.

Comment: I have heard this result attributed to Kronecker. You can prove it by computing the power of $p$ dividing a factorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a  corollary of Legendre's 1808 theorem that power of the prime $p$ that divides $n!$ is

$$  [n/p] + [n/p^2] + [n/p^3] +\: \cdots\ =\ \frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}$$

For this and much more see  Andrew Granville's very interesting survey [The Arithmetic Properties of Binomial Coefficients.](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/)

A full answer is [here](http://www.cs.cas.cz/portal/AlgoMath/NumberTheory/Arithmetics/Multiplication/Divisibility/PrimePowerDividingFactorial.htm).

Comment: Which chapter can i find my problem?

Comment: Math Gems - How do you prove the theorem you stated?

Comment: @Victor See also [this prior question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20737/prime-powers-that-divide-a-factorial) Also googling "power of prime divid factorial" finds many proofs. But you'll learn better if you discover it yourself - it's not hard.