# Binomial Coefficient Even or Odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

How to check whether the value of binomial coefficient nCr is even or odd ?

Comment: Well, you could always compute it, and look at the last digit. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem#Consequence

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  A more general result is described [in this previous Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/464857/3111), and the specific issue of [parity of binomial coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/cn-p-even-or-odd) is also previously asked.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can use the Vandermonde convolution $\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{m}{j}\binom{n-m}{k-j}$ (for any $0\le m\le n$) for the case when $n$ is even (choose $m=n/2$) (you will notice that $\binom{n}{k}$ is even when $k$ is odd in this case). When $n$ is odd, you can use a similar strategy.

But, of course, as in the links provided in the comments, you may also use the more involved theorem due to Kummer.

Comment: Can you please say how do you deduce that $\binom{n}{k}$ is even when $n$ is even, $k$ odd from your formula? I am having trouble seeing it.

Comment: Maybe by example is best: $\binom{4}{1}=\binom{2}{0}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{0} = 2\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{0}$. So it's always even.